# Find differential equation from general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have something like this:
$$y = \frac{Cx^2 + Cx}{Cx^2+ 1}$$
general solution. 
Can I find the differential equation itself from this general solution?
If yeah – how?

Comment: I don't understand the $Cx+Cx$ in the numerator. Would that not just simplify to $2Cx$?

Comment: Rearrange to $C=?$ and differentiate.

Comment: @math1000 this is example

Comment: You can always differentiate and find *some* differential equation that this function of $x$ satisfies. Whether or not that is the differential equation you are in search of...who knows?

Comment: @donald-splutterwit this is common method? tell more please

Comment: Multiply by the denominator and collect the $C$'s together
\begin{eqnarray*}
C(x^2+x-x^2y)=y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now divide by the bracket & differentiate.

Comment: @donald-splutterwit differentiate dy/dx ?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{y}{x^2+x-x^2y} \right)=?
\end{eqnarray*}
Quotient rule & implicit differentiation ... etc ....

Comment: @donald-splutterwit after that substituchion ? or just say that differentcial result = 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that an expression with $n$ arbitrary constants will yield a differential equation of order $n$. So to get the $n^{th}$ order derivative you'll have to differentiate the expression $n$ times, and in that process you'll obtain $n$ more relations so that now you have a total of $n+1$ relations from which you can eliminate the $n$ arbitrary constants to obtain the differential equation.

In your example

$$y = \frac{Cx^2 + Cx}{Cx^2+ 1}$$

there is only one constant $C$. Therefore, we can rearrange to form

$$y=C(x^2+x−x^2y)$$

by which we differentiate once to get

$$y'=C(2x+1-2xy-x^2y')$$

and since

$$C=\frac{y}{x^2+x−x^2y}$$

the above equation is

$$y'=\frac{2xy+y-2xy^2-x^2yy'}{x^2+x-x^2y}$$

which simplifies to the differential equation

$$y'=\frac{2xy+y-2xy^2}{x^2+x}$$